# Templates Default Arguments not working in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T = char>
T cast(T in){
 return in; 
}

int main(){
 std::cout << cast<>(5) << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Above will print `5` instead of an empty character, as the function is supposed to return a character by default and not an int. What am I ding wrong?

Edit:
Forcing it with `std::cout << cast<char>(5) << std::endl;` shows an empty character.

Comment: Why do you think it should print an *empty character* ?

Comment: try forcing it by this: `std::cout << cast<char>(5) << std::endl;`

Comment: @aep I think he means the ASCII control character 5, which would not print "5".

Comment: but should behave like when it forced like my example, it doesn't behave the same.

Comment: `cast<>(5)` will instantiate cast() function with `T=int`. It looks at the argument type to instantiate the template. If you want to force the argument deduction use `cast<char>(5)`.

Comment: if the template parameter is only meant to be the return type, consider `template<typename U, typename T = char> T cast(U in)`. Then you can use `cast<>(5)` to get a char.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of `5` is an integer by default. This causes 'T' to be overridden with the type int, rather than using your default type. If you really wanted the char of value 5 (which you probably don't), you could specify it as `'\x5'`.

For the ascii character 5....

```
int main(){
 std::cout << cast('5') << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Default types in templates tend to be useful when it's not easy to determine the template type, e.g. cast from int

```
template<typename T = char>
T cast(int v){
 return T(v); 
}
```

and now this will default to a method that casts an int to a char (rather than a int to int).

```
 std::cout << cast(53) << std::endl;
```

Comment: It would be good to back this up with quotes from the Standard or a trusted documentation site.